# Keep retrieving the first element in an array of data

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I keep retrieving the first element from the array, i do have 13 items in the array but every time i iterate through the array it keeps pulling out the first element and i does not increment.

How do i get i to increment and pull data out of the array for every element within the array?

This is then JSON:

```
[
   {
      "CategoryId":"1",
      "Name":"education"
   },
   {
      "CategoryId":"2",
      "Name":"allotments\r"
   },
   {
      "CategoryId":"3",
      "Name":"anti social behaviour\r"
   },
   {
      "CategoryId":"4",
      "Name":"police\r"
   },
   {
      "CategoryId":"5",
      "Name":"community \r"
   },
   {
      "CategoryId":"6",
      "Name":"council housing\r"
   },
   {
      "CategoryId":"7",
      "Name":"council\r"
   },
   {
      "CategoryId":"8",
      "Name":"doctors\r"
   },
   {
      "CategoryId":"9",
      "Name":"business\r"
   },
   {
      "CategoryId":"10",
      "Name":"disability \r"
   },
   {
      "CategoryId":"11",
      "Name":"employment\r"
   },
   {
      "CategoryId":"12",
      "Name":"money matters\r"
   },
   {
      "CategoryId":"13",
      "Name":"recreation"
   }
]
```

The code:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://localhost:8888/MAMP/WHFC/categories.php"]];

NSError *e;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&e];
NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//NSLog(@"%@", strResult);
NSArray *notifications = [data JSONValue];

int i = 0;
for (id obj in notifications){
    id myArrayElement = [notifications objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *CategoryId = [myArrayElement objectForKey:@"CategoryId"];
    NSString *Name = [myArrayElement objectForKey:@"Name"];
    if(NULL){

    }
    i = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: What you have should work (even if it is inefficient), but you don't show how you're trying to use the data during the iteration. (Why don't you use `obj` and keep a counter `i`?)

Comment: @Wain, i tried that also and keeps retrieving the first element in the array

Comment: And "i" never increments

Comment: Show how you're testing that. If true then your JSON parser is broken... Log `notifications` and show the result.

Comment: Whats the best json parser to use?

Comment: Or why not to use enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: method? It's anyway preferable and will keep track of indexes.

Comment: Did you try the built in `NSJSONSerialization`?

Comment: to remove all objects [array removeAllObjects];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NSJSONSerialization`

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://localhost:8888/MAMP/WHFC/categories.php"]];

NSError *e;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&e];
NSArray *arrCategoryList = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&parsedError];
```

Now `iterate`

```
for(NSDictionary *dictCategory in arrCategoryList)
{
   NSString *strCategoryId = [dictCategory objectForKey:@"CategoryId"];
   NSString *strCategoryName = [dictCategory objectForKey:@"Name"];
   NSLog(@"%@ : %@",strCategoryId,strCategoryName);
}
```

Comment: Still keeps retrieving the first element within the array

Answer (score 0):

```
    Sending **asynchronousRequest** will not block your main thread and ur UI Remain responsive. 


 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://localhost:8888/MAMP/WHFC/categories.php"]];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc]init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error1)
     {
         if (error1==nil && [data length]>0)
         {
             NSError* error;
             id jsonObject=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
             if (error==nil)
             {
                 if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
                 {
                     //handle dict here
                 }
                 else if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
                 {
                     NSArray* arrDict=jsonObject;
                     for (NSDictionary* dict in arrDict)
                     {
                         NSString *CategoryId = [dict objectForKey:@"CategoryId"];
                         NSString *Name = [dict objectForKey:@"Name"];
                         NSLog(@"Name= %@",Name);
                         NSLog(@"CategoryID = %@",CategoryId);
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Something bad happened");
         }
     }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSURL *s = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://localhost:8888/MAMP/WHFC/categories.php"]];
NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[self getAbsoluteURL:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:20.00];
NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc]init];
NSData *apiData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestURL returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSArray *arr = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:apiData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Here you got a `NSArry` from your JSON. After that for Parsing do this:

```
for(NSDictionary *dictionary in apiData) {
    NSString *cat = [obj objectForKey:@"CategoryId"];
    NSString *name = [obj objectForKey:@"Name"];
}
```

Hope this helps... :)